# Is there a way to target individual elements?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to target the bottom tds of just the first and second rows?
I have tried just using tr > td{border-bottom:black solid 1px;} but it goes through all tds.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index.html</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">


</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>        </td>
            <td>        </td>
            <td>        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>        
            <td>        </td>
            <td>        </td>
            <td>        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>        </td>
            <td>        </td>
            <td>        </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Heres what I have so far for css

```
td{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
tr > td:nth-of-type(1){
    border-right:1px solid black;
}
tr > td:nth-of-type(3){
    border-left:1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can use this:

```
tr:nth-of-type(-n + 2) > td:nth-of-type(-n +2){
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
}
```

working example:

```css
td{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
tr > td:nth-of-type(1){
    border-right:1px solid black;
}
tr > td:nth-of-type(3){
    border-left:1px solid black;
}

tr:nth-of-type(-n + 2) > td:nth-of-type(-n +2){
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index.html</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">


</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>        </td>
            <td>        </td>
            <td>        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>        
            <td>        </td>
            <td>        </td>
            <td>        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>        </td>
            <td>        </td>
            <td>        </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh wow thanks that helps a lot, the -n +2 is what targets just those two items i'm guessing.

Comment: `-n +2` targets the first 2 elements in `:nth-of-type`. So we have 2 `:nth-of-type`, one for `tr` and one for `td`. So we selected the first 2 elements of type td in each of the first 2 rows of type tr

Answer (score 1):

For a traditional grid of nine squares, you can use `table tr:not(:last-child) td` to target all cells in all rows except the last one:

```css
td{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
tr > td:nth-of-type(1){
    border-right:1px solid black;
}
tr > td:nth-of-type(3){
    border-left:1px solid black;
}
table tr:not(:last-child) td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index.html</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">


</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>        </td>
            <td>        </td>
            <td>        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>        
            <td>        </td>
            <td>        </td>
            <td>        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>        </td>
            <td>        </td>
            <td>        </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Changing that to `table tr:not(:last-child) td:not(:last-child)` will target the first two squares in each row, leaving the third column bare.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with `:nth-of-type` you can do for example this:

selecting nothing but the first 2 `tr` and nothing but the first 2 `td` inside

```css
td{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
tr > td:nth-of-type(1){
    border-right:1px solid black;
}
tr > td:nth-of-type(3){
    border-left:1px solid black;
}
table tr:nth-of-type(-n+2) td:nth-of-type(-n+2){
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index.html</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">


</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>        </td>
            <td>        </td>
            <td>        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>        
            <td>        </td>
            <td>        </td>
            <td>        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>        </td>
            <td>        </td>
            <td>        </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```